# Index exceeds matrix dimensions, when adding elements from structure

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

This is my code i get the error index matrix dimensions in this line: **`network.meansqrerr {n} = plus( network.meansqrerr {n}, mse( network.error));`|**

The objective of this line is sum of series  of meansqrr

for  this line `network.meansqrr {1} = [0 0 0 0 ]` because my values are quaterionic and i need to itilialise it

```
function network = BUILD(inputs, targets, iterations)
% regle pour determiner le noombre des neurones dans la couche caheée
% source: stackoverflow
% Determiner  hidden neuroness ( dans la couche caché couche2)
% round pour les virgules
nhidden = round((size(inputs, 1) + size(targets, 1)) * 2 / 3);
%
% fprintf(' le nombre des couches cachés est: ')
disp(nhidden) ;

% Create a neural network
% on determine le nombre des  neurones dans chaque couche
% couche1:  le nombre des entrées
% couche 3 (output) le nombre des classe
network = Create(size(inputs, 1), nhidden, size(targets, 1));
% Iteration variables
% SOMME Des erreurs quadratique
n = 1;
% Train network jusk le max des iterations
% zeros_quat(zeros (10,1));
while n <= iterations
    network.meansqrerr{1} = [ 0 0 0 0 ];
    % Training epoch
    % nombre des colonnes : size(inputs, 2)
    for i=1:size(inputs, 2)
        % Train network with inputs and target value
        network = traine(network, inputs(:,i), targets(:,i));
        % Update sum squared error
        network.meansqrerr {n} = plus(  network.meansqrerr {n}, mse( network.error));
        disp(['Iteration: ', num2str(n), ' / '    'Error: ',  num2str(double(network.meansqrerr{n})  )]);
        %
        % afficher les erreurs dans chaque iteration
        % disp(['Iteration: ', num2str(n), ' / '    'Error: ', num2str(network.meansqrerr(n) )]);
        % 
        % Update iteration number
        n = n + 1;
    end
    % afficher les poids
end
```

Comment: Your increment variable `n` is being changed at the end of the for loop rather than the while loop. That could cause some issues. I'd recommend doing a ctrl+a then ctrl+i (auto-indent code) and you'll see it immediately.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because `network.meansqrerr{2}` doesn't exist before your loop. You initialize `network.meansqrerr{1} = [0 0 0 0]` in the start of the loop. When you get to `n=2`, you haven't got a value for `network.meansqrerr{2}`, thus `... plus(network.meansqrerr{n}` will fail.